# Dealing with angry iron golems without a bow

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way to make iron golems friendly again/return to their original state?
One day in a village I was collecting wheat, and suddenly a villager stepped in front of me right as I was harvesting a stalk, and I accidentally punched the villager. Then the local iron golem came and started to attack me, so I ran into my house. I’m trapped inside because the golem is faster than me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An iron golem works like the wolf in terms of aggresivity, so you should do the following.

1. Gather up 3-4 stacks of dirt or other scaffolding.
2. Break out of the house through the ceiling and pillar up 10-15 blocks.
3. While crouching, build your way out of the village until the village’s chunks don’t render anymore. The iron golem will not follow you outside the village limit because of it’s AI.
4. Get down safely.
5. Wait for at least 20 minutes. (IRL)
6. You can now re-enter the Village safley.

P.S. An alternative is quickly opening the door to your house, hitting the golem and closing it again. Rinse and repeat until dead.

Comment: PPS: An alternative to the alternative is to build a murder-hole: a 1-block  opening which lets you punch the golem.

Comment: Ill try that thx

Comment: Digging might also be an option

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite remember, but I believe that killing the Golem might affect Villager happiness. So your options are to either run away (as [Detmondyou](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/331780/73976) has suggested), die, or rebuild villager happiness after you have killed the golem.

In the case of dying to the Golem, the main concern is loss of inventory. You can either set your spawn by building a bed, sleeping, then going out the next morning and dying to the golem, or you can change the gamerules to allow you to keep your inventory upon death. To do this:

1. If you don't have cheats allowed in your game, open the game to LAN, and allow cheats

   - Pause > Open to LAN > Allow Cheats: True
2. In the chat, type: `/gamerule keepInventory true` (you can copy and paste it from here - the capital "I" is important).

Now, when you die, you will respawn in your spawn location with all of your inventory, *and* all your XP; and the Golem (having dealt with the threat) will no longer be aggro'd.

---

Note: if you use the "Open to LAN" option to allow cheats in game, this will be the case until you turn it off again by opening your game to LAN (it will automatically close each time you exit your game). You can also switch your gamerule back (if you wish) by setting it to false, with cheats allowed:

`/gamerule keepInventory false`

Comment: You can also store your belongings in a chest to counter the entity despawn timer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just quit the game then start it again and it should be friendly

Comment: Can you back up your claim?

Answer (score 0):

You could go into Peaceful difficulty and then kill it since it won't be mad anymore.

Answer (score -3):

TL;DR- Get far away from the golems and they will stop trying to attack you.

A golem and I both went for the same zombie. I hit the golem on accident. I yelled, "I'm sorry! I'm sorry! I'm sorry!", as I ran for cover inside my house.

The golem and his 3 buddies (large village) started chasing me! I found cover and stood inside the tiny little 4x4 interior of the house, while the 4 golems circled, looking for a way to get me.

At one point, I got too close to the window and the golems hit me through the wall. So beware that's a thing, if anyone is in a similar situation.

I came here and found this post, looking for an answer. Not seeing any way to tame these 4 angry golems, I decided to run for the edge of the village and then wait for the timeout.

I stepped to the back of the house, so the golems would circle around there, then I ran for the door, out onto the narrow path between my house and the building next to me, hoping I could get around that building before the golems caught up with me. I ran to the edge of the village (or as far as I thought I should)

When I turned around to see where the golems were, I only saw one that had followed and he was 50 or so blocks behind me, standing there looking for me. After a few seconds, he turned around and went on his way.

I decided to make my way around to the side of the village, where I found 2 of the golems hanging out in a field with a couple of villagers. I approached cautiously, until I saw the golems recognize me. Neither of them came after me, so I assume they had lost their agro against me.

I cautiously made my way back through the village, testing the other golems and found I was in the clear.

So... They obviously changed the agro logic in the Bedrock edition of Minecraft. This whole event lasted maybe 5 minutes.

Comment: There is a lot of (entertaining but) unnecessary filler here. Your answer seems to be 'run outside of the city and the golems will turn passive'. In that sense it adds nothing to the approved answer.

Comment: The approved answer states you need to wait 20 minutes before re-entering. That was not required in my case. I shared my experience, so people could understand exactly what transpired.